# Invoked OOM killer

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, kodi, jdownloader

since about a year (maybe a bit more) i have constantly processes getting killed by linux oom-killer. The machine running is my htpc using ubuntu gnome 15.04 (currently).

The two process getting once a day or sometimes 10 times in a row killed are either KODI (formaly known ad XBMC) or my jdownloader usally ideling in the background.

The machine has 8GB of ram but no swap (never had). Beside hardware changes and a yearly os upgrade this is my setup for years. I can't tell for sure when this issue started but snice about a year i see either jdownloader or kodi getting killed randomly by the oom killer. I tried some memory logging and observed that i never ever had a memory usage of more than 35% of my 8GB ram.

Looking thourh various similar issues on the net didn't helped me, though maybe because i didn't understood much about this topic.

I never had such issues with the same software but an older ubuntu on my old 4GB ram htpc. I thought maybe jdownloader2 had a memory leak but i found nothing on the net about it nor have i ever observed that any of the processes used more than a few percent of ram.

I even swtiched to different kernels (currently mainline 4.0.5) but nothing helped.

anyhow, maybe someone can tell me what actually the problem is. Here some logs of the kills:

```
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.894944] Out of memory: Kill process 2421 (java) score 30 or sacrifice child
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.894949] Killed process 2421 (java) total-vm:3762816kB, anon-rss:236756kB, file-rss:648kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898004] kodi.bin invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898006] kodi.bin cpuset=session-c1.scope mems_allowed=0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898010] CPU: 2 PID: 20291 Comm: kodi.bin Not tainted 4.0.5-040005-generic #201506061639
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898011] Hardware name: ASUS All Series/H87M-PLUS, BIOS 2102 08/08/2014
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898012]  0000000000000000 ffff88006bc2b898 ffffffff817e4a5d 0000000000000007
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898014]  ffff8801e39e9400 ffff88006bc2b8e8 ffffffff817db4bc ffff880000000000
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898016]  000201da813ba498 ffff88006bc2b8c8 ffff8801f34b5a00 ffff8801f34b6170
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898017] Call Trace:
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898022]  [<ffffffff817e4a5d>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898024]  [<ffffffff817db4bc>] dump_header+0x7e/0xbd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898026]  [<ffffffff817db561>] oom_kill_process.part.9+0x66/0x30d
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898029]  [<ffffffff81187f5d>] oom_kill_process+0x8d/0xe0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898031]  [<ffffffff811881cb>] __out_of_memory+0x1bb/0x200
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898033]  [<ffffffff811883d9>] out_of_memory+0x69/0x90
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898036]  [<ffffffff8118ddb6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x906/0x9b0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898039]  [<ffffffff811d487c>] alloc_pages_current+0x9c/0x110
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898041]  [<ffffffff81183ed7>] __page_cache_alloc+0xc7/0xe0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898043]  [<ffffffff8118679d>] filemap_fault+0x29d/0x450
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898045]  [<ffffffff811b0a6d>] __do_fault+0x3d/0xa0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898047]  [<ffffffff811b07d0>] ? do_fault_around+0x100/0x110
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898049]  [<ffffffff811b46d9>] do_read_fault.isra.60+0x119/0x1f0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898052]  [<ffffffff816b5f5a>] ? ___sys_recvmsg+0xfa/0x240
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898054]  [<ffffffff811b4c50>] do_fault.isra.62+0x70/0x80
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898057]  [<ffffffff8123bff4>] ? fsnotify+0x204/0x260
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898059]  [<ffffffff811b4cd6>] handle_pte_fault+0x76/0x190
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898062]  [<ffffffff810b16d6>] ? update_curr+0x1e6/0x1f0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898064]  [<ffffffff811b51fb>] __handle_mm_fault+0x1db/0x360
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898066]  [<ffffffff811b5430>] handle_mm_fault+0xb0/0x160
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898070]  [<ffffffff810666f0>] __do_page_fault+0x190/0x470
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898072]  [<ffffffff81066b5e>] do_page_fault+0x3e/0x80
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898074]  [<ffffffff817f3388>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898075] Mem-Info:
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898076] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898078] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898079] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898079] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898080] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898081] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898082] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898083] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898084] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898085] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898085] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898086] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898087] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898088] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898089] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898092] active_anon:337875 inactive_anon:1543501 isolated_anon:0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898092]  active_file:1474 inactive_file:3005 isolated_file:124
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898092]  unevictable:16 dirty:121 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898092]  free:25249 slab_reclaimable:17325 slab_unreclaimable:9626
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898092]  mapped:19173 shmem:1554352 pagetables:9117 bounce:0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898092]  free_cma:0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898094] Node 0 DMA free:15864kB min:136kB low:168kB high:204kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15888kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:16kB slab_unreclaimable:8kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898097] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3171 7652 7652
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898099] Node 0 DMA32 free:45724kB min:27952kB low:34940kB high:41928kB active_anon:604284kB inactive_anon:2511080kB active_file:2440kB inactive_file:5432kB unevictable:48kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):256kB present:3329528kB managed:3249408kB mlocked:48kB dirty:164kB writeback:0kB mapped:41284kB shmem:2534644kB slab_reclaimable:31044kB slab_unreclaimable:14212kB kernel_stack:3024kB pagetables:14212kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:49584 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898102] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 4480 4480
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898104] Node 0 Normal free:39408kB min:39492kB low:49364kB high:59236kB active_anon:747216kB inactive_anon:3662924kB active_file:3456kB inactive_file:6588kB unevictable:16kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):240kB present:4716544kB managed:4588280kB mlocked:16kB dirty:320kB writeback:0kB mapped:35408kB shmem:3682764kB slab_reclaimable:38240kB slab_unreclaimable:24284kB kernel_stack:5472kB pagetables:22256kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:64136 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898107] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898109] Node 0 DMA: 2*4kB (U) 4*8kB (U) 5*16kB (UE) 2*32kB (UE) 3*64kB (UE) 3*128kB (UE) 1*256kB (E) 1*512kB (E) 2*1024kB (UE) 2*2048kB (ER) 2*4096kB (M) = 15864kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898118] Node 0 DMA32: 2941*4kB (UEM) 2524*8kB (UEM) 842*16kB (UEM) 13*32kB (EM) 6*64kB (M) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 46228kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898124] Node 0 Normal: 3397*4kB (UEM) 2759*8kB (UEM) 217*16kB (UEM) 10*32kB (UM) 1*64kB (M) 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 39516kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898131] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898133] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898133] 1559092 total pagecache pages
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898134] 0 pages in swap cache
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898135] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898136] Free swap  = 0kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898137] Total swap = 0kB
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898137] 2015515 pages RAM
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898138] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898139] 52121 pages reserved
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898139] 0 pages cma reserved
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898140] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898141] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898146] [  321]     0   321    10593      324      21       2        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898148] [  326]     0   326     8336      767      20       2        0             0 systemd-journal
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898151] [  744]     0   744    97809     1024      79       3        0             0 NetworkManager
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898152] [  745]   100   745    63974      177      27       3        0             0 rsyslogd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898153] [  747]     0   747    71973      748      44       4        0             0 accounts-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898155] [  750]     0   750     4795       42      14       2        0             0 atd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898156] [  752]     0   752    84103      312      66       3        0             0 ModemManager
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898158] [  765]   110   765    94482      913      83       4        0             0 whoopsie
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898159] [  771]   111   771     7578       74      19       3        0             0 avahi-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898161] [  781]     0   781     7136       89      17       2        0             0 systemd-logind
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898162] [  782]     0   782     7974       75      20       3        0             0 cron
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898164] [  788]   101   788    10897      358      27       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898165] [  820]   111   820     7547       60      18       3        0             0 avahi-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898167] [  826]     0   826     4860       61      14       3        0             0 irqbalance
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898168] [  841]     0   841     8282      102      19       3        0             0 lircd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898169] [  858]   103   858     9779       77      19       2        0             0 dnsmasq
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898171] [  889]     0   889    70058      528      39       4        0             0 polkitd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898172] [  895]     0   895    20523      192      42       3        0             0 cups-browsed
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898174] [  966]     0   966    14910      176      33       2        0         -1000 sshd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898175] [  969]     0   969   111029      227      50       3        0             0 gdm
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898177] [  997]     0   997   575927    11692    1126       5        0             0 Xorg
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898178] [  999]     0   999     1099       46       8       3        0             0 acpid
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898179] [ 1006]     0  1006    62529      266      61       4        0             0 gdm-session-wor
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898181] [ 1013]     0  1013     4705       41      13       3        0             0 agetty
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898182] [ 1019]  1000  1019    10655      173      23       2        0             0 systemd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898184] [ 1020]  1000  1020    15710      468      34       2        0             0 (sd-pam)
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898185] [ 1023]  1000  1023     8654      187      20       3        0             0 upstart
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898187] [ 1097]  1000  1097     5819       46      14       2        0             0 upstart-udev-br
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898188] [ 1103]  1000  1103    10763      306      25       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898189] [ 1129]  1000  1129   108514      232      41       3        0             0 gnome-keyring-d
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898191] [ 1140]  1000  1140     5295       49      12       2        0             0 upstart-dbus-br
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898192] [ 1145]  1000  1145     7452       72      17       2        0             0 upstart-file-br
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898194] [ 1151]  1000  1151     5312       92      11       2        0             0 upstart-dbus-br
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898195] [ 1156]  1000  1156    87553      292      36       3        0             0 ibus-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898197] [ 1166]  1000  1166    49123      161      31       3        0             0 gvfsd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898198] [ 1169]  1000  1169   300456     1898     208       4        0             0 gnome-settings-
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898200] [ 1173]  1000  1173    66031      140      30       2        0             0 at-spi-bus-laun
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898201] [ 1174]  1000  1174   173663     1000      99       3        0             0 gnome-session
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898203] [ 1178]  1000  1178    10597      122      25       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898204] [ 1181]  1000  1181    67422      153      30       3        0             0 gvfsd-fuse
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898205] [ 1184]  1000  1184    67373      652      34       4        0             0 ibus-dconf
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898207] [ 1185]  1000  1185   113517     1872     111       3        0             0 ibus-ui-gtk3
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898208] [ 1189]  1000  1189    74474      458      75       3        0             0 ibus-x11
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898210] [ 1200]  1000  1200    30799      108      28       2        0             0 at-spi2-registr
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898212] [ 1209]     0  1209    68254      306      53       2        0             0 upowerd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898213] [ 1253]  1000  1253    48438      135      30       3        0             0 ibus-engine-sim
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898215] [ 1259]  1000  1259   125712      790      94       3        0             0 pulseaudio
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898216] [ 1260]   107  1260    42239       60      20       4        0             0 rtkit-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898217] [ 1267]   113  1267    77189     1396      51       2        0             0 colord
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898219] [ 1276]  1000  1276   104415      399      97       4        0             0 gsd-printer
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898220] [ 1277]  1000  1277   345854    21174     300       4        0             0 gnome-shell
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898222] [ 1295]  1000  1295   114934      823      77       4        0             0 gnome-shell-cal
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898223] [ 1299]  1000  1299   311685     2297     169       3        0             0 evolution-sourc
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898225] [ 1329]  1000  1329   223131     2490     166       4        0             0 goa-daemon
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898226] [ 1404]  1000  1404    28894      187      25       3        0             0 gvfsd-metadata
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898228] [ 1482]  1000  1482    75375      289      49       3        0             0 mission-control
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898229] [ 1491]     0  1491     7655      105      19       3        0             0 wpa_supplicant
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898230] [ 1504]   120  1504     8916      157      22       2        0             0 ntpd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898232] [ 1511]  1000  1511    73086      383      43       3        0             0 gvfs-udisks2-vo
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898233] [ 1514]     0  1514    92688     1080      46       3        0             0 udisksd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898235] [ 1523]  1000  1523    50225      162      32       3        0             0 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898236] [ 1527]  1000  1527    47182      130      29       3        0             0 gvfs-mtp-volume
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898238] [ 1531]  1000  1531    81299      232      45       3        0             0 gvfs-afc-volume
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898239] [ 1536]  1000  1536    48448      660      31       4        0             0 gvfs-goa-volume
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898241] [ 1544]  1000  1544   624748    38411     390       6        0             0 tracker-extract
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898242] [ 1546]  1000  1546    91334      581      42       3        0             0 tracker-miner-a
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898244] [ 1548]  1000  1548    94688     2473      46       4        0             0 tracker-store
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898245] [ 1549]  1000  1549   259771     3143      75       4        0             0 tracker-miner-f
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898246] [ 1550]  1000  1550    82239      541      48       4        0             0 tracker-miner-u
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898248] [ 1580]  1000  1580   568588    14848     241       4        0             0 evolution-calen
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898249] [ 1689]   106  1689     8848       77      21       3        0             0 kerneloops
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898251] [ 1754]     0  1754     6010      111      17       3        0             0 mysqld_safe
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898252] [ 1755]     0  1755     6494       55      17       3        0             0 logger
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898253] [ 1894]     0  1894   109303     3661     154       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898255] [ 1930]   119  1930   160349    34344     118       4        0             0 mysqld
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898256] [ 1956]     0  1956    51380      381      95       2        0             0 nmbd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898257] [ 1984]     0  1984    71703      568     133       2        0             0 smbd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898259] [ 1985]     0  1985    71703      536     129       2        0             0 smbd
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898260] [ 2280]   121  2280    13334      164      27       2        0             0 exim4
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898262] [ 2288]  1000  2288   147736     4820     139       4        0             0 guake
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898263] [ 2290]  1000  2290    13672      170      31       3        0             0 gconfd-2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898265] [ 2292]  1000  2292    44689      191      24       4        0             0 dconf-service
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898266] [ 2293]  1000  2293     3713       39      13       3        0             0 gnome-pty-helpe
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898268] [ 2294]  1000  2294     6672      748      17       3        0             0 bash
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898269] [ 2392]  1000  2392     1118       38       7       2        0             0 JDownloader2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898270] [ 2434]  1000  2421   940704    60246     362       7        0             0 java
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898272] [ 2449]  1000  2449    67530      156      32       3        0             0 gvfsd-burn
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898273] [ 2480]  1000  2480   105638     1563      61       4        0             0 gvfsd-dav
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898275] [ 2637]  1000  2637   125067     1010      98       3        0             0 zeitgeist-datah
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898277] [ 2644]  1000  2644    66533      200      29       4        0             0 zeitgeist-daemo
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898278] [ 2655]  1000  2655    58442      271      38       3        0             0 zeitgeist-fts
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898280] [ 2668]  1000  2668     2587       20      10       3        0             0 cat
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898281] [ 2866]  1000  2866   193559     2479     208       3        0             0 evolution-alarm
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898282] [ 3046]  1000  3046    88488      936     106       4        0             0 update-notifier
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898284] [ 3103]  1000  3103    73302      222      44       3        0             0 deja-dup-monito
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898285] [ 4331]    33  4331   113321     8037     163       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898287] [ 4332]    33  4332   113458     8122     163       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898288] [ 4333]    33  4333   112672     7364     161       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898290] [ 4334]    33  4334   111790     6722     160       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898291] [ 4335]    33  4335   112677     7472     161       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898293] [ 5831]    33  5831   112682     7441     162       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898294] [10233]    33 10233   112677     7409     161       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898295] [16574]    33 16574   112669     7558     161       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898297] [17627]    33 17627   112669     7215     161       2        0             0 apache2
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898299] [20289]  1000 20289     1118       20       7       2        0             0 kodi
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898300] [20291]  1000 20291   798345    56471     477       6        0             0 kodi.bin
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898301] [20392]  1000 20392     6655      731      17       3        0             0 bash
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898303] [20414]  1000 20414    14816      108      35       3        0             0 su
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898304] [20416]  1001 20416     6689      768      19       3        0             0 bash
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898306] [20660]     0 20660     1118       33       7       2        0             0 runvdr
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898307] [20674]   118 20674   236747    29748     118       4        0             0 vdr
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898309] [20827]  1001 20827     3139       44      11       2        0             0 less
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898311] Out of memory: Kill process 10368 (java) score 30 or sacrifice child
Jun 14 14:02:26 htpc kernel: [47784.898313] Killed process 2434 (java) total-vm:3762816kB, anon-rss:238400kB, file-rss:2584kB
```

Comment: the installed java version is:
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

(godammit... why does it post when i press <enter> to get a new line???)

BUT, i recently discovered that jdownloader brings an own jre with it.. It was a sun java 1.7.4x version. I removed that to force it using my installed java i posted above. It didn't made any difference regardinig my issue. I also add the Xmx1024 option to the startup script.


How do i add a new line here???

Comment: update-java-alternatives -l  shows this:
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: for now at least it seemed better (i wouldn't say solved) by executing "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/compact_memory" once a minute via a cron job and also setting /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes to 256 MB (default was 66MB).

I found some hints about that somewhere posted at since then it seems to help. But it is too early to tell for sure. Anyhow, it at best just circumvents the real issue. I would prefere to identify the problem and maybe get it fixed.

Comment: well, the two things i did seemed to be a working workaround. no oom kills anymore. Not sure if both are needed, though.

Somehow i think something broke during the past x linux kernel version as it seems to fail defragmenting and reclaiming memory automaticaly. if i find some time i do some more tests and will open a bug report.

Comment: just a small update: it still happens all the time. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

May be memory fragmentation is the reason why the OOM killer be triggered if there is still memory available.you can read the detail in [this article](http://bl0rg.krunch.be/oom-frag.html).